# C# console application: write to PowerShell console without sending to pipeline?

Tags: c#, powershell

I have the following C# .Net core application.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ???.WriteLine("yyy"); // Need to display "yyy" always even when running $a = .\test.exe in the powershell console
        Console.WriteLine("xxx"); // "xxx" can be sent to the PowerShell pipeline
    }
}
```

The following Powershell code assigns "xxx" to `$a`. I want to display "yyy" on the console.

```
$a = .\Test.exe # $a got "xxx". Nothing is displayed
```

What if I want to output some other text to console before assigning the final result to `$a`?

Comment: you mean you want to log a value which isn't returned to the powershell script? It's not really clear. $a will not be populated until Test.exe completes, so `Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");` will already "output some value to console before assigning the final result". Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve precisely?

Comment: When running `$a = .\Test.exe` in PowerShell. Nothing is displayed

Comment: "When running $a = .\Test.exe in PowerShell. Nothing is displayed " ...sorry, but in the question you said "The following Powershell code will get "Hello World"." .Now you're saying it doesn't. Which is it?

Comment: I want "Hello World" to be assigned to $a. And display some other text on the console screen when run `$a = .\test.exe`

Comment: @ADyson What the OP means is that the output of the executable is assigned to the variable instead of written to the host console. I'm not sure the latter is even possible, though, since AFAIK the differentiation between host console and output streams is a PowerShell concept, whereas executables are supposed to be working outside PowerShell too.

Comment: Ok, I think I see. "I want "Hello World" to be assigned to $a"...As far as I understand it, that is what already happens. "display some other text on the console screen when run $a = .\test.exe"...I don't think .NET will do that. .NET can run "Console.WriteLine", which pipes that text to the standard output (normally the console if you run it directly in a cmd.exe command prompt) but Powershell intercepts that output and pipes it to $a instead. the .NET code does not control what happens to the output.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers ok I think I get it now, thankyou. I think there was perhaps a little linguistic semantic difficulty. I have commented above what I think is happening. Would you agree?

Comment: @ADyson My understanding is that the OP wants the executable to write some output directly to the host console and other output to StdOut (so that it can be assigned to a variable when invoking the command from PowerShell). But like I said, I'm not sure that's even possible.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I think we are in agreement then :-)

Comment: How about Debug.WriteLine?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: It _is_ possible, by writing to _stderr_ (the standard error stream), which PowerShell by default passes through to the console.

Comment: @mklement0 That I'm aware of. However, StdErr and the host console are different things as you know. Not only technically, but also semantically.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: Yes, good point, PowerShell hosts aren't necessarily _consoles_, but, given that the code in the question assumes a console host - as evidenced by use of the `Console` API - writing to stderr is a viable solution.

Comment: @mklement0 From a "write output to different streams" perspective: yes. However, speaking from an admin perspective: I just hate it when programs (or scripts for that matter) abuse StdErr for non-error status output.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers: I know that this conflation of true error output and status information is unfortunate, but, due to having only _2_ streams available, applications have no choice but to output _anything that isn't data_ to stderr. That is still preferable to polluting stdout with status information. Success vs. failure should only ever be inferred from a process' _exit code_ anyway, not from the presence / absence of stderr output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sup>Note: The following applies to running PowerShell in a *console window* (terminal), as is typical, but note that is possible to host PowerShell in non-console applications as well.</sup>

Your only option is to write the text you don't want PowerShell to capture via its success output stream to *stderr* (the standard error stream) rather than *stdout* (the standard output stream):

- `Console.WriteLine()` is effectively the same as `Console.Out.WriteLine()`, i.e. it writes to *stdout*, which PowerShell maps to its *success output stream*, which means that the output can be captured in a variable or passed through the pipeline for further processing.
- `Console.Error.WriteLine()`, by contrast, writes to *stderr*, which PowerShell *passes through to the console* (the display) by default (see below for how to capture it).

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Error.WriteLine("yyy"); // -> stderr; prints to the console by default
        Console.WriteLine("xxx"); // "xxx" can be sent to the PowerShell pipeline
    }
}
```

Note that it is possible to also capture *stderr* output, namely via redirection `2>`:

- `2>&1` merges stderr output into PowerShell's success output stream so that output from both stderr and stdout can be captured; note that lines received via stderr are actually captured as `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord` instances.
- `2> stderr.txt` saves stderr output to file `stderr.txt`

Note that while regular console programs only have *2* output streams - stdout and stderr - PowerShell internally supports *6* output streams, as described in [about_Redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection).<sup>[2]</sup>

---

<sup>[2] At the system level, only stdout and stderr exist as output streams for communication between processes, so PowerShell must map its internal streams to them both when receiving output from and sending output to external programs.</sup>

Answer (score -1):

If you put $a on its own line in the Powershell script, it will be written to the console.

```
$a = .\Test.exe # $a got Hello World. Nothing is displayed
$a # <== this line should write the value of $a to the console
```

Comment: I need to display different value from $a to console

Comment: The question is about how to make `Test.exe` _also_ write something that _isn't_ captured when you assign to a variable in PowerShell.